# how to remove cache from webView

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, android-webview

I have recyclerView and in each items I've have displaced facebook in webView. I loged in one of the item (position 1) of the webview by facebook. And, all other items (position 1,2,3..) are automatically logged in same fb account. But, I want to login different fb account in different item.

this is my activity:

```java
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setSavePassword(true);

        code = getIntent().getStringExtra(MainActivity.FB);

        assert code != null;
        switch (code) {
            case "fb1":
                webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com");
                break;
            case "fb2":
                webView.clearCache(true);
                webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com");
                break;
            case "fb3":
                webView.loadUrl("https://www.facebook.com");
                break;
        }
    }
```

I tried to add `webView.clearCache(true);` in one but, It is also not working. Once different facebook is logged in different items, I don't want user to enter login details again. Can you please help me?

*I don't want to clear cache, but I want to disconnect the link between webview of different list. I mean, if I login one user in one webview, all webview are showing same user. And, if I use `clear cache` user must enter login details again and again.*

Comment: try looking for "webview cookie" first

Comment: @yyp how? can you please explain more?

Comment: how about using different WebView for each item?

Comment: @yyp I tried that, i didn't work

Comment: Impossible I think. Just like google chorme you can not save many user facebook account sesson. You have to clear sesson cache each account. Another solution but I dont try yet you should reseach about save facebook sesson in webview for one. Clear all and load it by user you want

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way. Hope it should work.

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
       cookieManager.removeAllCookies(new ValueCallback<Boolean>() {
      
         @Override
         public void onReceiveValue(Boolean aBoolean) {
               Log.d(TAG, "Cookie removed: " + aBoolean);
         }
       });
}
else {
cookieManager.removeAllCookie()
}
webView.clearCache(true);
webView.clearFormData();
webView.clearHistory();
```

Comment: Once different facebook is logged in different items, I don't want user to enter login details again.

Comment: @madan if you dont want to user to enter login details again, then how can you ensure its secure. How can make the login details at first place ?

Comment: @cantona_7 I mean, suppose there are 5 items in my recyclerView, I want to load 5 different facebook account in those 5 items. It is for my personal use.

Comment: @cantona_7 and I don't want cache to be cleared coz if I do so, I should enter login details again and again while opening facebook.